# Hide ViewPager tabs when scrolling up.

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

how can I create a similar effect to the tab bar in the Android Twitter App - which is always on and if we scroll down its scrolls up with the ListView and disappears. Similar thing is done in Chrome browser on Android and the Facebook Android app.

It appears again when scrolling up.

Normal (ViewPager):

[image]

Hidden (ViewPager):

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @David Do you have solution?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this below options for your solution.

1) [Sticky Header](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/)
2) [Sticky Listview](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems)
 
3) [Header Listview](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/)

apply library as per your usage.

if above library not work because of viewpagerindicator. then remove viewpagerindicator and then try to apply normal header by changes background onclick event. and then apply same library.

Comment: I can't see how any of these would help -- I need to hide the ViewPager tabs in the ActionBar when user scrolls down on the ListView.